# elixir absinthe custom scalar :datetime import error

Tags: elixir, absinthe

i have create so many **schema**, but when i try to import custom scalar type `:datetime` from absinthe. then it was giving me error like this

```
== Compilation error in file lib/project_name_web/schema.ex ==
** (Absinthe.Schema.Error) Invalid schema:
/home/vinay/Documents/project_name/lib/project_name_web/schema.ex:3: Absinthe type identifier :date is not unique.

  References to types must be unique.

  > All types within a GraphQL schema must have unique names. No two provided
  > types may have the same name. No provided type may have a name which
  > conflicts with any built in types (including Scalar and Introspection
  > types).

  Reference: https://github.com/facebook/graphql/blob/master/spec/Section%203%20--%20Type%20System.md#type-system

/home/vinay/Documents/project_name/lib/project_name_web/schema.ex:3: Type name "Date" is not unique.

  References to types must be unique.

  > All types within a GraphQL schema must have unique names. No two provided
  > types may have the same name. No provided type may have a name which
  > conflicts with any built in types (including Scalar and Introspection
  > types).

  Reference: https://github.com/facebook/graphql/blob/master/spec/Section%203%20--%20Type%20System.md#type-system

/home/vinay/Documents/project_name/lib/project_name_web/schema.ex:241: Joining_date :utc_datetime is not defined in your schema.

  Types must exist if referenced.

/home/vinay/Documents/project_name/lib/project_name_web/schema.ex:253: Purchased_at :utc_datetime is not defined in your schema.

  Types must exist if referenced.

/home/vinay/Documents/project_name/lib/project_name_web/schema.ex:136: Joining_date :utc_datetime is not defined in your schema.

  Types must exist if referenced.

/home/vinay/Documents/project_name/lib/project_name_web/schema.ex:171: Purchased_at :utc_datetime is not defined in your schema.

  Types must exist if referenced.


    lib/absinthe/schema.ex:271: Absinthe.Schema.__after_compile__/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:677: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

i have also imported `import_types(Absinthe.Type.Custom)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO found solutions from here https://elixirforum.com/t/reusing-imported-graphql-type-definitions-in-absinthe/8519/2?u=imvinaypandya

i was importing this `import_types(Absinthe.Type.Custom)` each and every schema (**for example: user_type.ex, contact_details.ex** etc). so i have just imported this only once in **schema.ex** file and that worked for me.